# Creating absolute time from NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c

It looks easy, but I couldn't figure out a proper way to do this. I need to create an `NSString` from a `NSDate` which represents the same time on every device, independently from the iPhone's time zone settings.

Suppose `userA` is in London, where the actual time is 14:00, `userB` is in New York where is 9:00 and `userC` is in Hong Kong, where the actual time is 21:00.

```
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
```

Actually with this code I'm getting these results (when I log the `dateString`):

- userA: `08/12/14 14:00:00`
- userB: `08/12/14 09:00:00`
- userC: `08/12/14 21:00:00`

But I need to create dates like this

- userA: `08/12/14 14:00:00`
- userB: `08/12/14 14:00:00`
- userC: `08/12/14 14:00:00`

My goal is to create a "system/absolute time" which is the same inside the app and doesn't matter the original time zone of the user's device. The end result must look like this `MM/dd/yy HH:mm:s`.

Is it possible to get the `NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];` from a pre-defined timezone? For example it could always use the actual time of the GMT-00 timezone.

I've tried to do it with this code, but when I run the code, the console writes out the wrong date (based on the device time zone setting) again, so I don't have a better idea. I would appreciate any ideas.

```
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

dateFormatter.timeZone  = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"Europe/London"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
NSLog(@"the date is %@,", dateString);
```

Comment: Because it's not an abbreviation what you are feeding there. Other than that you are perfectly on the right track.

Comment: @Desdenova What do you mean exactly? What should I do different?

Comment: `Europe/London` is not an abbreviation. It's probably returning `nil` and the device gets the time zone from the system. `GMT` is an abbreviation for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GMT timezone conversion in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871727/gmt-timezone-conversion-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code should work. What ever the timezone you are in it will always display the time in UTC.

```
NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[[NSTimeZone alloc] initWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Between the following two threads, I think you'll find everything you need (and thensome). The [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539638/objective-c-conversion-between-timezones) is an extensive example of a problem similar to yours (just remember to look at the code in the answers and not the question), while the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871727/gmt-timezone-conversion-in-objective-c) has all the time zone abbreviations that you'll ever need.  Gotta love the helpful people on The Stack.

The links again, just in case

[objective-c: Conversion between TimeZones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539638/objective-c-conversion-between-timezones)

[GMT timezone conversion in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871727/gmt-timezone-conversion-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *localDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yy";

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: localDate];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";


NSString *dateString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate: localDate];
```